# Determining if a point is perpendicular to a line

Tags: c++, mathematics, mesh

I am trying to walk a line that is intersecting a mesh, and given the point on the line I need to see what vertices may be perpendicular to it. My initial idea was to attempt a dot product between the line's direction vector and the direction vector from the point on the line to the mesh's vertex, and then only accept values that were near 0. This resulted in a collection of vertices behind the point on my line. Playing with the threshold values for the dot product check do not seem to help either. Any ideas?

### Code

```
//actual_pos = position of the vertex
//trav_in_soace = point along the line
//m_fireDir = normalized direction vector of the line

Vector3 dir_to_point = actual_pos - trav_in_space;
dir_to_point.Normalize();

float dot_accept = DotProduct(m_fireDir, dir_to_point);
if (dot_accept > max_threshold || dot_accept < min_threshold)
    continue;
```

### Picture with threshold values near 0.5

This is best result I can get and it is still really inaccurate. The orange verts are the points on the purple line, the red and blue are what should be the desired vertices.

[image: The orange is the point on the purple line, the red and blue are what should be the desired vertices.]

Comment: How can a point be perpendicular to anything?

Comment: Think of it as the line between the point on the line and vertex as what is perpendicular.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just calculate the normal vector to the plane that passes through the given point, then use that to determine a point on the plane... then find the nearest vertex (lattice point, I assume) to that?

Comment: A plane can be defined as a point and a normalized direction, I have that from the line direction and point on the line. how could i determine if a point is on that plane while allowing for some uncertainty

Comment: You can measure the distance between a point and a plane

Comment: I don't understand the question. *"Think of it as the line between the point on the line and vertex as what is perpendicular."* For *any* line and *any* point, there is such point on the line that the original line and the line between two points are perpendicular.

Comment: I'm also having trouble understanding what you're asking for here. Maybe if you told us a bit about how you're applying this logic in your game, it would help us understand what you're trying to do. What do these points and lines represent in your game scenario? What's the significance of the perpendicular condition?

Comment: Ok, so i am testing ductility on a mesh and need to transfer force through the body. the perpendicular part is essentially me trying to find the slice of vertices to affect at each physics step along the direction of impact.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that the dot product math was sound and doing what it was suppose to, but elsewhere I had a space transformation that i didn't need that caused the point on the line to be in a different location. removing that transform fixed my problem.

Comment: As written right now, if another user had a similar problem, reading this answer wouldn't give them much guidance about how to solve it. If you include some examples of the code you changed, or explain your steps in more detail, you might be able to save future gamedevs some time with this problem. :)